# IndexOf method Java

Tags: java, list, generics, collections, equals

My method `indexOf` is supposed to return the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in a list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element. More formally: returns the lowest index `i` such that (`E == null ? get(i) == null : E.equals(get(i))`), or -1 if there is no such index. The problem with this code is that it always seems to return -1, any suggestions on how I can fix this?

```
 public int indexOf(E element) {

    Node current = head;
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (current.getmElement() == element) {
            return index;
        }
        index++;
        current = current.getmNextNode();
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I am using generics to find the next element in the list:

```
public class Node<E> {
private E mElement;
private Node<E> mNextNode;

Node(E data) {

    this.setmElement(data);
}
public E getmElement() {
    return this.mElement;
}
public void setmElement(E element) {
    this.mElement = element;
}
public Node<E> getmNextNode()
{
    return this.mNextNode;
}
public void setmNextNode(Node<E> node)
{
    this.mNextNode = node;
}}
```

Comment: Use equals rather than ==

Comment: The `head` field is not resolvable in the code.

Comment: `E.equals(get(i))`, as described in text, is not the same as `E == get(i)` (Note: no need for `index`, should always be same as `i`, or better IMO, no need for `i`, loop until current is `null` (assuming that means end of list))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing a refernece check: `current.getmElement() == element`. What you meant to do is to check if those objects are equal:

```
current.getmElement().equals(element)
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I edit my == to equal and remove index and just use i, I will have problems with current= current.getmNextNode(); instead. Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: It says it is an Unreachable statement.

Comment: It means the code cannot be executed. It's hard to tell with the code provided. Can you place another question with more code? If this answer was helpful, consider marking as correct.

Comment: Yes I placed another question.